# No match for operator + 2D string array pointer notation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to get familiar with pointers so I'm working on a code that has a pointer to a 2d array in it.

Here's my pointer declaration in my main:

```
    string board[10][10];
    string *b = &board[0][0];
```

The pointer is then passed to a function and I want to store contents into that array using the pointer. This is where the trouble comes in.

```
void clearBoard(string *b) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        cout << i << " ";
    } cout << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        cout << r + 1;
        if (r < 9) {
            cout << "  ";
        } else {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            *(*(b + r) + c) = "-";             <-- where problem occurs
            cout << *(*(b + r) + c) << " ";    <-- i can imagine there's a problem here to
            if (c == 9) {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run this program this appears:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} and 'int')|
```

I believe that I tried to access the pointer how my book shows me, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: *I believe that I tried to access the pointer how my book shows me,* -- I bet your book is showing you how to access 1-dimensional arrays, and you're erroneously trying to extend that to 2D arrays.  No book I know of would have a C++ programmer write code in this fashion to manipulate a 2D array.

Comment: Arrays of arrays are not the same as pointer to pointers. And you don't even have a pointer to a pointer. Also learn that for any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is easier to read and understand. And also explains the problem: `*(*(b + r) + c)` is the same as `b[r][c]` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: By the way, lot of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your code, together with plenty of one-letter undecipherable variables. Use longer descriptive names.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm sure that my book is addressing 2D arrays, as is this website: https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/pointers-and-2-d-arrays/. It might be because I'm using strings rather than ints that causes the problem? I'm not sure tho. (My book uses longs for the example)

Comment: All arrays can decay to a pointer to its first element. For a "1D" array like e.g. `string some_strings[X]` then it will decay to `&some_strings[0]` which have the type `string*`. You have a "2D" array (actually an array of arrays), which will also decay to a pointer to its first element: `board[0]`. But in your code you have an array of arrays, so the pointer type i pointer to array (os `string)`, or `string (*)[10]`. This is *very* different from the argument you pass to `clearBoard`. Your variable `b` is of the wrong type to be pointing to an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

So lets break down that line of code:

```
*(b + r) + c

     *(         // Dereferencing something, we will see what later
        b + r   // Adding an int to a string*, fine, we are moving where we point in 
                // the array
      ) + c     // Woops we dereferenced the above, it was a string*, so now it is a 
                // string. adding integer c to a string, can't be done!
```

So it looks like you are dereferencing a 2d array. Normally, you would just do it like:

```
board[row][col]
```

But since you are trying to understand pointers, you want to use string*. So lets check out this array. It will look something like this:

```
[[row1], [row2], ...]
```

So we can take a pointer to the start and consider it as a contiguous piece of memory. But how do we find the right pointer? Well, lets imagine we have the following info (which we do):

```
row, col, num_rows, num_cols
```

The common way to get a 1d pointer from 2d array indexes is like this:

```
row * num_col + col
```

*As an excersize, you should write on paper a small 2d array and understand how this works*.
So you can make a function, like this:

```
string* getIndex(string* s, row, col, num_col) {
   return s + (row *num_col + col);
}
```

And use this to get the right position in the string.